# Read mtom message with http inbound gateway

Tags: spring-integration

Following the examples I tried to build a sample to receive an mtom message with multipart/related as content-type without success.

Any idea if spring-integration supports receiving multipart/related as content-type?

Any help is appreciated

Here's my xml:

```
<int-http:inbound-gateway request-channel="channel" 
        path="/services/mtom" supported-methods="POST" reply-channel="response"
        request-payload-type="java.lang.String"
        message-converters="messageConverters">
    </int-http:inbound-gateway>

    <util:list id="messageConverters">
        <bean class="org.springframework.integration.http.converter.MultipartAwareFormHttpMessageConverter"/>
    </util:list>
```

and here's the message I'm sending

```
POST http://localhost:8080/http-multipart-sample/services/mtom HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml"; start="<rootpart@soapui.org>"; start-info="text/xml"; boundary="----=_Part_28_207620374.1499207113979"
SOAPAction: ""
MIME-Version: 1.0


------=_Part_28_207620374.1499207113979
Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=UTF-8; type="text/xml"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-ID: <rootpart@soapui.org>

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ws="http://ws.redstrawberry.middleware.fing.edu/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ws:receiveOrder>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <order>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <imageData><inc:Include href="cid:463691671957" xmlns:inc="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include"/></imageData>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <dateTime>1994-11-05T08:15:30-05:00</dateTime>
            <productId>1</productId>
            <quantity>2</quantity>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <transactionId>1111</transactionId>
         </order>
      </ws:receiveOrder>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
------=_Part_28_207620374.1499207113979
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=soapui-5.1.3.jar
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <soapui-5.1.3.jar>
Content-Disposition: attachment; name="soapui-5.1.3.jar"; filename="soapui-5.1.3.jar"
```

**EDIT:**

web.xml:

```
<display-name>multipart-http</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Multipart</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/servlet-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        <multipart-config>
            <location>/home/tom/tmp</location>
            <max-file-size>1000000000</max-file-size>
            <max-request-size>1000000000</max-request-size>
            <file-size-threshold>1048576</file-size-threshold>
        </multipart-config>             
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Multipart</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
public void receive(Message message ) throws MessagingException, IOException{
        logger.info("###############################\nSuccessfully received multipart request: " + message);
    }

Successfully received multipart request: GenericMessage [payload=byte[0], headers={content-length=11634876, http_requestMethod=POST, host=localhost:8080, http_requestUrl=http://localhost:8080/http-multipart-sample/services/mtom, content-type=multipart/related;type="application/xop+xml";start="<rootpart@soapui.org>";start-info="text/xml";boundary="----=_Part_73_763506982.1499348711151", connection=Keep-Alive, id=3a74250d-db39-6b87-200e-7b79071590b2, accept-encoding=gzip,deflate, user-agent=Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5), timestamp=1499348723970}]
```

new SI configuration:

```
<int-http:inbound-channel-adapter channel="channel" 
        path="/services/mtom" supported-methods="POST" message-converters="messageConverters">
    </int-http:inbound-channel-adapter>

    <util:list id="messageConverters">
        <bean class="sample.MTOMHttpMessageConverter"/>
    </util:list>

    <int:channel id="channel"/>

    <int:service-activator input-channel="channel" >
        <bean class="sample.MultipartReceiver"/>
    </int:service-activator>

    <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"/>



public class MTOMHttpMessageConverter<T> extends AbstractHttpMessageConverter<Object>{

@Override
public boolean canRead(java.lang.Class<?> clazz, org.springframework.http.MediaType mediaType) {
    return true;
};

@Override
protected Object readInternal(Class<?> clazz, HttpInputMessage inputMessage)
        throws IOException, HttpMessageNotReadableException {
}
```

Comment: Why don't use WS Inbound Gateway on the matter? http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.0.M5/reference/html/ws.html#mtom-support

Comment: Because it's a generic http endpoint that accepts basic soap messages and mtom messages. This endpoint receives the message and then it routes it to the corresponding ws-services using ws-addressing header

Comment: I'm afraid you have to right your own custom `HttpMessageConverter` on the matter. If you need content, of course. If you are fine with just raw data, you can expect  request-payload-type="byte[]" and route it to the corresponding ws-services using ws-addressing header.

Comment: thanks Artem! I tried to make my own HMC but no parts are injected on the httpServletRequest. Any Idea? I updated with my web.xml. I'm using Tomcat 7

Comment: sorry, I must say, no parts are injected on the DefaultMultipartHttpServletRequest. On the other side, I developed a basic Servlet based on MimeMultipart and worked fine, but I wish to do it on SI, any idea?

Comment: Try from here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.0.M5/reference/html/http.html#multipart-rest-inbound

Comment: And here : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/intermediate/multipart-http

Comment: I followed the docs but no payload is on the Message. Is a byte array of length zero. I edit with the service activator implementation and logs

Comment: I'm afraid that you need more work there then just have `multipartResolver`. You still need custom `HttpMessageConverter` to parse that SOAP package wrapped to the HTTP.

Comment: I added the converter (see new edit) and the DefaultMultipartHttpServletRequest inside de inputMessage has an empty array of Multiparts. Do I have to add any other config to inject the parts? I'm using Java 8, Tomcat 7 and SI 4.3.1

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you with that. I have never worked with MTOM close and I don't have any ideas what's wrong. I just tried to provide you as much as possible info.